# How to change the value stored at an memory address

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I try to modify a value that is stored at a certain memory address.

The address is stored in a certain pointer but altering it with a new int changes the memory address (of course).

```
int *toModify = (int *)(foo+5); //foo is a adress of a function. 
//The val to alter is 5bytes after it
int newVal = 5;
toModify = &newVal;


//implementation of foo
int foo(){
return 42;
}
```

Lets say toModify has value 42. I want to change it to 5.
How can I achieve to store the change in the address of toModify?

Comment: You're trying to overwrite a constant in program space using pointers which are declared as pointing to variables in RAM and are relying on the compiler placing that constant 5 bytes after the function starts. This needs rethinking.

Comment: It's more an experiment. I can rely that this is always 5bytes after function start

Comment: Adding 5 to an int* will add 20 bytes not 5.  You would need to cast to a char* then an int*.

Comment: Suggest you read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code#Operating_systems

Comment: because you CANNOT relay that it is always 5bytes after function start, (play a bit with optimization options on your (or other) compiler and you'll see), you should never do anything like this in high level programming languages. However, in assembler, you can simply set the code segment writable and rely on the positions of labels/instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by modifying the memory page the value ist stored in with mprotect. Then you can access the address and write to it

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in a portable, standards compliant way. Even if you wanted to do this in a non-portable way (which you may be able to do by manipulating the machine code directly), `foo` is likely in read-only memory, and so can't be modified.

It would be better to define `foo` to access a global or static variable, which you could change. For example:

```
static int n = 42;

int foo() {
    return n;
}

// when you want to modify it
n = 5;
```

Comment: What if I change foo to read/write memory?

Comment: @AzzUrr1 That number is probably inside a MOV instruction. You'll need advanced knowledge of the architecture and compiler to get a non-portable solution that is probably killed by opmitizations. Do it some other way

Comment: @AzzUrr1 You can't necessarily do that; many systems protect against changing the executable code of a program to prevent exploits. This is well beyond the realm of what you can do portably; so if you want platform specific details, please specify a platform and what you are actually trying to do, and we may be able to help you find a better way.

Comment: @Guido It's true that this is going to involve some advanced architectural knowledge, but things like this are possible. For compatibility reasons, I've had to patch out binary code in third party programs before; but it's not a general purpose C question at that point any more, it's a very special purpose, architecture and OS dependent problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
toModify = &newVal;
```

use

```
*toModify = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `foo` is the name of a function, then first do this:

```
int *toModify = (int *)((char *) foo + 5);
```

This first converts `foo` from a pointer to a function to a pointer to `char`. This allows you to work with it as a pointer. Normally, you cannot perform arithmetic with pointers to functions, so you need a pointer to an object type. The C standard does not guarantee that this conversion will work, so you must ensure that your C implementation supports it.

We convert it to a pointer to `char` so that adding five adds five bytes, not five units of another object type. Then we convert the sum to a pointer to `int` so that it may be assigned to `toModify`.

Then do this:

```
int newVal = 5;
memcpy(toModify, &newVal, sizeof newVal);
```

This attempts to copy an `int` with value five to the place pointed to by `toModify`. This avoids one problem in attempting to directly assign the value with `*toModify = 5;`, which is that the assignment aliases the bytes in violation of the rules of the C standard, so the behavior is not defined by the standard, although it may be supported by some C implementations. However, it has other problems.

First, the bytes at this address might not be writeable by your program. Modern operating systems typically use memory protection to prevent code from being modified improperly, and this protection will cause the `memcpy` to fail.

Second, even if the bytes are writeable and the `memcpy` modifies them, that does not guarantee they will be seen by the part of the processor that executes instructions. Bytes in the instruction stream are typically cached by modern processors, and changing the bytes in memory will not change the bytes in cache. Usually, it is necessary to execute special instructions to flush the instruction cache. The method for doing this is dependent on the target processor and operating system.

If you are doing this to experiment with modifying code simply as a learning exercise, this is not the right way to do it unless you are working in a special embedded environment that supports this. If you are attempting this for another reason, you almost certainly should abandon it and seek another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Perreal's (delete) answer is right:

```
*toModify = newVal;
```

... but... you're trying to write a into the application's code space, and modern operating systems go to great lengths to prevent this, as it's a *major* security risk. That's probably why you'll probably get a segmentation fault.

Also, you're writing an int (maybe a 4-byte value on your system?) at an address `(foo+5)` which is not aligned to a 4-byte boundary. Again, your hardware may not support this,

If you want to modify a byte, you need this.

```
char * toModify;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is usually read-only on unix. It is often read-only on embedded systems because it's physically located in flash memory.

On UNIX you can get around this by using [ptrace()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) with PTRACE_POKETEXT.